# How do I query my backend (ExpressJS/MongoDB) to get data in chunks (eg get 10 results, process them, then get the next 10, etc.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, get

I am trying to figure out a way to send and handle a request which potentially has a large number of results (coming from Mongo). I would like to request datasets of a certain size (eg. 10 records), process them, and then request the next set. I'm not sure if this functionality is already built in or if I have to code it all myself.

I'm looking for something like:

```
let result =[]

let request = httpRequest('GET', 'URLAPIendpoint/size=10');

while(request){
    //process request value
    request.next();
}
```

I've tried looking through the Express documentation but I'm not sure what to look for.

This is kind of it but not really.
`const result = student.find().limit(10)`

I'd like the call for "next set of 10" to be coming from the client. So, the connection would stay open and the client would notify the server to send the next set.

Comment: You have 3 types of communication. 1) Client sends a request, server sends a response 2) Client opens a WebSocket, and client and server communicate like in a chat 3) Server-sent events. Which of these 3 types do you want to use?

Comment: I suppose "Client opens a WebSocket, and client and server communicate like in a chat" feels appropriate

Comment: The reason I would want a websocket open is to maintain a connection and a state on the server side. I'm picturing an API endpoint which pulls data from Mongo and holds onto that collection so that the server can ask for the next set without it having to query the DB again.

Comment: Now, you got your keyword and the next steps should be clear. Do you have a question?

Comment: I'm taking a run at implementing a websocket interface. I'll check back in with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are trying to achieve pagination functionality. You can do this by using skip and limit on top of cursor. Also in the url you need to get the pageSize and pageNumber.

Your query may look like

```
const result = student.find().skip(pageSize*(pageNumber - 1)).limit(pageSize)
```

Also if querying data size is the problem for you then if you are using any native MongoDb driver you will only get the cursor for a query and the cursor batches 100 records by default and it is configurable. So that only when you iterate over the 100 records and trying to read 101st record the next set of 100 records is pulled from the server.

Comment: Pagination is certainly a practical application of this. What I'm looking for is the client side asking for a set of data in sets of a defined size. The server would only send that many and would wait for a signal from the front end to send the next set until there are no more.
I'm concerned with multiple calls to Mongo. It's my understanding that Mongo does not guarantee record order. To me, that implies that a call for the first set of ten records and then a separate request for the next ten could share entries.

Comment: If you do query with sorting you will get the records in order. By that way you will not get duplicates. Something like this: const result = student.find().sort({_id:1}).skip(pageSize*(pageNumber - 1)).limit(pageSize)